# Convert to DateTime from two string variables in C#

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime

I want to convert two string variables to a DateTime variable.
So something like this...

```
string day = "05";
string month = "11";
Convert.ToDateTime(day + month + "0000");
```

This will then be uploaded to a SQL server smalldatetime datatype.
Is there any way to do this? I've seen some people use ParseExact but they use it with a perfect date format, never creating it from two strings like I want to do. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: wht should be the year ? 0001?

Comment: (which by the way is not a possible a year for the smalldatetime type in sqlserver) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: what do you need to do exactly ? store only a month and a day, without year ?

Comment: Something like: `DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, int.Parse(month), int.Parse(day));` ?

Comment: The day and month only matter as it represents when a school year ends, the application I'm making will take the month and day. And I forgot that SQL only supports certain years, I'll set the year to any year that is viable. I'll give your idea a go now Jimi.

Comment: The answer that @Amit posted does the same thing with a slightly different tool.

Comment: Semantically, a "DateTime" type doesn't make sense in your situation, IMHO. You should be better off storing month and day as integers separately. OR use a DateTime format, but with an actual year correpsonding to the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string day   = "05";
string month = "11";
string year  = "0001";
DateTime dt  = 
 DateTime.ParseExact(day + "-" + month + "-" + year, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But year must not be 0.

**'0001' year represent first year only. so you can say 0 years has been passed till this date.**

**UPDATE**

as jimi mentioned below

> [smalldatetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) goes from 1900-01-01 to 2079-06-06. The OP will have to safe-check this range before converting.

you would have to be careful while parsing string into Date, if you are going with `smalldatetime`, you are limited with range of "1900-01-01 to 2079-06-06" so your `DateTime` cannot have year 0001 at that time.

Comment: [smalldatetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) goes from `1900-01-01` to `2079-06-06`. The OP will have to safe-check this  range before converting.

Answer (score 1):

> The day and month only matter as it represents when a school year ends, the application I'm making will take the month and day.

If you are not using any specific year, **don't use a date time type!**

The dateTime format will need a year, as already stated, and using a fake one will just convey a lot of false information with it (for instance, the day of week, Monday, Tuesday, ...). Of course you don't want to use it, and you probably won't, but you could be victim of some display bug and other unwanted consequences.

**I'd suggest you simply use two integer fields, one for the day and one one for the month.**

For *validation* purpose, you could internally use some dateTime following the other accepted answer for instance. That would be one way to prevent "31st April".

But I recommend you to avoid storing a fake year in your db, along with a complicated type, that could cause you more trouble than needed in the long run.

---

On the other hand, if your app is supposed to refer to the current year or other specific, then use it, don't fake it either !